# Reading Strings from different programs

Tags: c#

I'd like to actually get some strings out of other programs and would like to display them on my program. On the picture, you'll be able to see it. If something is unclear, tell me. I'd like an advice on how to start on this - How I could get the data to my Form.

[image: Getting Data from a Bot to Form]

I've considered about finding out its address from something like Cheat Engine, but I'm not sure, whether that works and which address it might be exactly and stuff. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply, no you can't read like that.

Comment: @orhun.begendi Actually you probably can, but it involves some extremely low level Windows API calls, and you need to figure out the target control you're trying to read - very complicated.

Comment: Yes, you can. Post the process name of the target process and whether this is the main window. You'll need P/Invoke.

Comment: What do you mean @IllidanS4 I didn't really get the point, sorry. The main process is mBot, the target process is the windows forms application.

Comment: Do you mean different forms.  See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: No they're two different programs. One is a Windows Forms Application, one is a program made by someone else. The programs do not have any connection with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it: I've opened up **Cheat Engine** and tried to **find the Address** of my Level. I guess it was a **4 Byte value**, so I searched for my Current Level. **Each time** I leveled up, I **searched for a changed value**. Only some addresses were left => Found the Address => **Made a pointer scan on the address and found out the base address.** 
Afterwards I used **"ReadProcessMemory"** to read the Address its value. I put this in a timerloop which allowed me to refresh the level.

Hope this helps you guys.